# Trying to figure out how to migrate old system to DDD concepts

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am reading Eric Evans' book about DDD. I really like the concepts in the book. I started to think how I can migrate an old project to this newly(for me) discovered concepts.
Of course some issues raised in my head. So I am asking for help.

Let me give you context. The project is small CMS which managing issues and their content.
The application should support following structure:

- Publisher it is the root entity
- Publication it is "child" of Publisher
- Issue it is "child" of Publication
- Section it is "child" of Issue
- Page it is also "child" of Issue, think of it as image
- Article it can be child of Issue or Section

Page and Article are the two types which hold the actual content.
So this is the structure which we defined with the business. The two most important functionalities are "Parsing" and "Publishing".

1. Parsing means to read data from external source for now XML file and create an Issue and the related content - articles and sections or pages.
2. Publishing it is a flag which shows whether the content should be displayed or not. The problem is this flag should be updated across all content starting from the issue.

My thoughts on this: All objects described above should be entities because they need to be individually findable so they need Id. Then I think they should be aggregates as well because they contains some side logic and in case of some objects they may contains other entities or value objects. So I will refer to each aggregate by some kind of identifier object which also will tell me the relation between the entities.

I have two problems with the main functionalities.

1. Parsing - I read that we should save/update only one aggregate per request. When we parse content we receive a list of aggregates, which holds issue and its content and I need to store it to the DB. Which means I have list of aggregates and I have to bend the rule. Not only that but imagine what will happen if I parse 60 or more articles for an issue and the application fire OnCreate event for every article, page or section. What will be your approach here.
2. Publishing - actually is pretty much the same problem I have to update 60 aggregates and the same case here with events.

There should have a way to model this with DDD concepts but I am still trying to find it and every time when start reading I can not stop thinking about this scenarios.

What will be you approach to this scenarios by using DDD?
Also if you see that this approach is to DB oriented please let me know what will be your ides?

Answer (score 0):

The DDD book is awesome, but doesn't have much code in it. If you have some time, read [Implementing Domain-Driven Design](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/implementing-domain-driven-design/9780133039900/) as it has a ton of code examples.

The concept you might be looking for is a [*saga* or *long running process*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/implementing-domain-driven-design/9780133039900/ch04lev2sec11.html). Sagas orchestrate changes to multiple aggegrates, depending how it's implemented, you could think of it as a workflow and in each stage a different aggregate is updated. It's important that sagas can be continued if the app goes down while running.

From a pragmatical approach, in the past I did update multiple aggregates inside one transaction as adding sagas can introduce a lot of complexity in a project. I think it's ok as long as all aggregates are modified from the same place (ideally one short method) and there are no interactions between the aggregates. For example, imagine you have to publish a bunch of resources, so the solution is to loop over multiple aggregates invoking a method that will publish them).

## edit

Going a bit through memory lane, I found these articles wrote by Vaughn Vernon (the author of the book I mentioned above) which touches this subject: https://www.dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/